# Upgrade 10.04LTS to 10.10 problem

Tags: 10.10, 10.04, upgrade

```
Checking for a new ubuntu release
Done Upgrade tool signature
Done Upgrade tools 
Done downloading            
extracting 'maverick.tar.gz'
authenticate 'maverick.tar.gz' against 'maverick.tar.gz.gpg' 
tar: Removing leading `/' from member names

Reading cache

Checking package manager
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
Building data structures... Done 
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done
Building data structures... Done 

Updating repository information
WARNING: Failed to read mirror file


A fatal error occurred 

Please report this as a bug and include the files 
/var/log/dist-upgrade/main.log and /var/log/dist-upgrade/apt.log in 
your report. The upgrade has aborted. 
Your original sources.list was saved in 
/etc/apt/sources.list.distUpgrade. 

Traceback (most recent call last): 

File "/tmp/tmpe_xVWd/maverick", line 7, in <module> 
sys.exit(main()) 

File "/tmp/tmpe_xVWd/DistUpgradeMain.py", line 158, in main 
if app.run(): 

File "/tmp/tmpe_xVWd/DistUpgradeController.py", line 1616, in run 
return self.fullUpgrade() 

File "/tmp/tmpe_xVWd/DistUpgradeController.py", line 1534, in 
fullUpgrade 
if not self.updateSourcesList(): 

File "/tmp/tmpe_xVWd/DistUpgradeController.py", line 664, in 
updateSourcesList 
if not self.rewriteSourcesList(mirror_check=True): 

File "/tmp/tmpe_xVWd/DistUpgradeController.py", line 486, in 
rewriteSourcesList 
distro.get_sources(self.sources) 

File "/tmp/tmpe_xVWd/distro.py", line 103, in get_sources 
source.template.official == True and 

AttributeError: 'Template' object has no attribute 'official'
```

This is what i got when i tried to upgrade the desktop edition:sudo do-release-upgrade.
One more info: I have kde installed.

Answer (score 2):

The first hit on Google (searching for "AttributeError: 'Template' object has no attribute 'official'") yields the next Ubuntu Forums thread: [Upgrading to 10.10: "AttributeError: 'Template' object has no attribute 'official'"](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1595020).

Try refreshing your package list and make sure that your system is up to date before upgrading to 10.10:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: I still got problem, please refer to this result:http://askubuntu.com/questions/32064/update-upgrade-problem