# Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick/Release

Tags: 10.04

```
Get:1 http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg [197B]
Hit http://archive.canonical.com maverick Release.gpg                          
Ign http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ maverick/partner Translation-en_IN    
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com maverick-security Release.gpg         
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-security/main Translation-en_IN
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-security/restricted Translation-en_IN
Hit http://archive.canonical.com maverick Release                    
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-security/universe Translation-en_IN
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-security/multiverse Translation-en_IN
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com maverick-security Release                       
Hit http://archive.canonical.com maverick/partner Packages                     
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com maverick-security/main Packages       
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com maverick-security/restricted Packages 
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com maverick-security/main Sources        
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com maverick-security/restricted Sources  
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com maverick-security/universe Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com maverick-security/universe Sources
Ign http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable/main Translation-en_IN
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com maverick-security/multiverse Packages 
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com maverick-security/multiverse Sources
Get:2 http://dl.google.com stable Release [1,347B]
Get:3 http://dl.google.com stable/main Packages [1,096B]
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick Release.gpg                          
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick/main Translation-en_IN       
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick/restricted Translation-en_IN
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick/universe Translation-en_IN
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick/multiverse Translation-en_IN
Get:4 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates Release.gpg [198B]
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-updates/main Translation-en_IN
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-updates/restricted Translation-en_IN
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-updates/universe Translation-en_IN
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-updates/multiverse Translation-en_IN
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick Release       

Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates Release

Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick/main Packages
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick/restricted Packages
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick/main Sources
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick/restricted Sources
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick/universe Packages
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick/universe Sources
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick/multiverse Packages
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick/multiverse Sources
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/main Packages
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/restricted Packages
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/main Sources
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/restricted Sources
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/universe Packages
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/universe Sources
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/multiverse Packages
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/multiverse Sources
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick/main Packages
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick/restricted Packages
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick/main Sources
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick/restricted Sources
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick/universe Packages
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick/universe Sources
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick/multiverse Packages
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick/multiverse Sources
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/main Packages
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/restricted Packages
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/main Sources
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/restricted Sources
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/universe Packages
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/universe Sources
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/multiverse Packages
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/multiverse Sources
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick/main Packages
  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http:
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick/restricted Packages
  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http:
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick/main Sources
  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http:
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick/restricted Sources
  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http:
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick/universe Packages
  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http:
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick/universe Sources
  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http:
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick/multiverse Packages
  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http:
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick/multiverse Sources
  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http:
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/main Packages
  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http:
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/restricted Packages
  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http:
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/main Sources
  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http:
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/restricted Sources
  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http:
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/universe Packages
  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http:
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/universe Sources
  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http:
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/multiverse Packages
  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http:
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/multiverse Sources
  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http:
Fetched 2,838B in 5min 12s (9B/s)
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick/Release  

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick-updates/Release  

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick/main/binary-i386/Packages.gz  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick/restricted/binary-i386/Packages.gz  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick/main/source/Sources.gz  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick/restricted/source/Sources.gz  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick/universe/binary-i386/Packages.gz  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick/universe/source/Sources.gz  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages.gz  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick/multiverse/source/Sources.gz  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick-updates/main/binary-i386/Packages.gz  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick-updates/restricted/binary-i386/Packages.gz  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick-updates/main/source/Sources.gz  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick-updates/restricted/source/Sources.gz  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick-updates/universe/binary-i386/Packages.gz  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick-updates/universe/source/Sources.gz  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick-updates/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages.gz  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick-updates/multiverse/source/Sources.gz  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http:

W: Some index files failed to download, they have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

This is what I got when update, I am using 10.04 LTS, once I tried to upgrade to 10.10, but ended up with error, since then all the updates are done from maverick, as you can see. Now I'm facing problem both in update and upgrade(release upgrade too). Is there a way to restore everything to its default, or anything else...

Comment: This question has useful, upvoted answers; it seems unlikely it was correctly closed. In particular, note that we do not close answered questions for being about old releases. I am voting to reopen this.

Answer (score 14):

Me too had the problem, i am from India. So by default india servers selected. I changed it simply by going to "System" menu and on submenu "Administration" selected "Software sources". Their changing india server to "main" server not helped me.

So clicked the "other" option in "Download from" and then clicked on "select best server" button, which inturn tested 350 servers and selected the best reachable servers. After that no errors, all my update went so nicely and speedy too.

try the same.

Comment: Yes, the Indian servers are troublesome. I have the same problem, and I always either do a pingtest, or just set them to the Japanese servers.

Answer (score 11):

You could try an other mirror, like `http://archive.ubuntu.com/`. Run the next command to replace all occurrences of `http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/` with `http://archive.ubuntu.com/`:

```
sudo sed 's@http://in\.archive\.ubuntu\.com/@http://archive.ubuntu.com/@' -i /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Next, proceed with an update:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Followed by an upgrade or install:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install [package-name]
```

If it does not help, you can undo the previous change:

```
sudo sed 's@http://archive\.ubuntu\.com/@http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/@' -i /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Comment: I had the same problem with the norwegian servers (no.archive.ubuntu.com)

Comment: If you need to adapt the `sed` commands, run them with `-i.backup` instead of `-i` to not dstroy your original files when something goes wrong. (Or test them without `-i` (in place editing))

Answer (score 0):

run the command "sudo /usr/bin/software-properties-gtk"
1)It will open the software sources window,then select download from other,then select Best server,it will check the best server for you.
2)choose that server.close the window,now run the "sudo apt-get update"

Comment: This won't work.  The reason it's not working is maverick (10.10) is end of life.  There is a question [here](http://askubuntu.com/q/91815/107450) on installing software in end of life versions but I'd always recommend upgrading instead.

Answer (score 0):

You run into much of the same errors if you build a docker container from an outdated image. I had this with `W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found`, and it also showed the failed index downloads.

If you put the image tag a step higher, it can download from the URL again. Not sure how this might help when dealing with a Linux upgrade, but it may help those who run into this warning: `W: Some index files failed to download, they have been ignored, or old ones used instead.` and see such version conflicts. If you can, play around with the versions.