# What can be done when the repositories listed in sources.list go down

Tags: apt, repository

For many days I was trying to do `apt-get update` and I used to get a error: `could not connect to server`. I had thought it must be a issue related to my machine. Later, accidentally, when I copied and pasted a link from the sources file onto browser address bar I found that it was because the resolving of domain names of the repositories for my country was failing. I, painfully, edited the sources.list files on all my 3 machines from `in.archive` to `us.archive`. And it worked fine. So, my question is isn't it possible to specify multiple repositories existing is different locations?

Comment: You're not the only one with issues with the Indonesian repo, see [this question](http://askubuntu.com/q/32064/6969). I've never had problems with ubuntu's mirrors, multiple repositories are therefore not needed.

Comment: It's Indian repo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is completely possible to specify multiple repositories, for example:

```
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty main restricted
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty main restricted
```

If the same versions of the same packages are found in both listed repositories, apt will download the files from the first listed repository.  If the first repository is out of date, and the second has newer files, then apt will pull from the second listed repository.  If either of the repositories are down, apt will pull from the repository that remains up.

Note that you will still see complaints in your package managers if either repository is down, although this should not adversely affect your ability to download software unless all repositories are down.