# Changing the update server from india to main server: 404  Not Found

Tags: 10.04, server, apt, updates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Failed to fetch in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick/Release](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32064/failed-to-fetch-http-in-archive-ubuntu-com-ubuntu-dists-maverick-release)

I recently installed Ubuntu 10.04.2 server and like to upgrade the packages to the latest. Unfortunately India based server errors out and  would like to switch to main server.

some snippet of errors are given below.

```
Get:32 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates/main landscape-common 11.02-0ubuntu0.10.04.1 [227kB]
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates/main landscape-common 11.02-0ubuntu0.10.04.1
404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.140 80]
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates/main libavahi-common-data 0.6.25-1ubuntu6.2 
404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.140 80]
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates/main libpq5 8.4.8-0ubuntu0.10.04
404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.140 80]
```

Looks like some of the servers are down. Where can I find the URLs of main server to update in /etc/apt/sources.list ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick/Release](http://askubuntu.com/q/32064/6969)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a [thread asking the same](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1131855&page=1) question in the ubuntuforums. [Answer #13](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=7123397&postcount=13) is the way to go. You could also look at the answer [another question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32064/failed-to-fetch-http-in-archive-ubuntu-com-ubuntu-dists-maverick-release/32075#32075) asked here not so long ago. Next time use google.

Btw. if you have a graphical interface installed this is MUCH easier than editing the sources.list:

[image]

P.S.
Sorry. I overlooked the comments.

Comment: This question pertains to 10.04 server, not 10.04 desktop and it does not have GUI

Comment: Lekensteyn's comment points to correct answer. I wanted to exact URLs of main server