# ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS driver error

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, 22.04, xorg

I hadn't been on my pc for a good couple months and after booting up and running updates along with steam updates I go to my home to find my steam crashed. I think nothing of it to reboot and my screen was not fitted to screen size. After doing more updates I wanted to get rid of the non-fitted screen size I boot xserver graphics and it worked to get rid of the screen fit, but i am now stuck on xserver graphics and cant get back to any of the nvidia-530 graphics. After clicking on the graphics and trying to upgrade to them i am faced with this.[image]

I have tried `nvidia-smi` here is what I gotin response.[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing the update server from india to main server: 404  Not Found](https://askubuntu.com/questions/44656/changing-the-update-server-from-india-to-main-server-404-not-found)

Comment: @karel I would like to thank you for that. After switching servers from US to main and a couple of restarts later i am sitting on the nvidia 535  drivers thanks