# Error while configuring Ubuntu archive mirror

Tags: virtualbox

I'm trying to install Linux on my vitrual machine (created through Oracle VM VirtualBox) but stuck with configuration ubuntu mirror error. What should I do to resolve this? Thanks for your help! [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQMEo.png)

Comment: Did you check network connectivity and that system clock is correct?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick/Release](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32064/failed-to-fetch-http-in-archive-ubuntu-com-ubuntu-dists-maverick-release)